# Microsoft graph toolkit (mgt) can't get user in mgt-person

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, spfx

I have problem to get user inside *mgt-person* tag. If I use *person-query="me"* I get my acc with no problems but when I use for expamle *person-query="another user e-mail"* it has no result.

How should person-query looks like? Can it be *person-query="email@email.com"* or is it bad format?

```
<div className={ styles.mgtDemo }>
 <div className={ styles.container }>
   <div className={ styles.row }>
     <mgt-person person-query="user@domain.cz" show-name show-email person-card="hover">

     <template data-type="person-card">
     <mgt-person-card person-details="{{person}}" 
         person-image="{{personImage}}">
       <template data-type="additional-details">
         <h3>Stuffed Animal Friends:</h3>
         <ul>
           <li>Giraffe</li>
           <li>lion</li>
           <li>Rabbit</li>
         </ul>
       </template>
     </mgt-person-card>
   </template>

     </mgt-person-card>
 </mgt-person>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Can anybody help me with that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out by my self. **user-id** (or **userId**) practicaly mean user login name to tenant. So it could be for example `user-id="surname@tenantname.com"` depends on admin choice.